# web2py use of modules

Tags: python, module, web2py, scheduler

I have a python function in modules in web2py to send e-mails.It has the following code

```
message = response.render('scheduler/connectionmessage.html',cont)
```

I get the error

```
<type 'exceptions.NameError'> name 'response' is not defined"
```

How can I make render available in modules? The objective is to have a few such scripts under modules and execute them via scheduler from a stub under controllers.
More code -

```
def send_email_invites():
  from gluon import *
  from gluon.template import render 
  db = current.db
  ......<execute query and populate dictionary>
  message = response.render('scheduler/connectionmessage.html',cont)
```

That is about it.

Comment: Can you show us the module code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code already includes `from gluon import *`, which means you have imported the thread local `current` object. That object includes the `response` object for the current request, so you should refer to `current.response` rather than just `response`.

Note, this is not necessary in model, controller, and view files because those files are executed in a global environment that already includes the `response` object (along with much of the rest of the web2py API).

For more details, see http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#Accessing-the-API-from-Python-modules.

Comment: As per Bibhas' suggestion, I changed the import * to from gluon import current. That should be fine, right?

Comment: That should be fine as long as `current` is all you need. Actually, although I get the general admonition against `import *`, in the case of `from gluon import *`, that gets you the entire web2py API, just as you would have it in any model, view, or controller file (it does not actually import all the individual modules in gluon -- see [here](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/master/gluon/__init__.py#L13) for what it includes), so in this case it's probably OK. Of course, if you really are just using one or two objects from the API, then sure, go ahead and be explicit about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this before calling `response.render()`

```
from gluon.globals import Response 
response = Response()
```

And I know it's tempting, but try to avoid `from xyz import *` and be explicit.

Comment: Error -   File "/var/www/web2py/applications/scheduler/controllers/jobs.py", line 5, in index
    return send_unsent_email_invites.send_email_invites()
  File "applications/scheduler/modules/send_unsent_email_invites.py", line 25, in send_email_invites
    message = response.render('scheduler/connectionmessage.html',cont)
  File "/var/www/web2py/gluon/globals.py", line 399, in render
    self._view_environment.update(self._vars). May be I am making progress.

Comment: That means the exception you were getting initially has been solved. It's a new exception. You are welcome to create a new question iff you cannot find the answer yourself, you may also update this question with new exception.

Comment: Although that changes the exception, it doesn't solve the initial problem, which requires access to the `Response` object associated with the current request. Creating a new `Response` object won't help. Instead, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/21261293/440323.